# Analyzing spikes in performance measurement

Tags: c++, performance, performance-testing, benchmarking

I have a set of  C++ functions which does some image processing related operation. Generally I see that the final output is delivered in 5-6ms time range. I am measuring the time taken using `QueryPerformanceCounter` Win32 API. But when running in a continuous loop with 100 images, I see that the performance spikes up to 20ms for some images. My question is how do I go about analyzing such issues. Basically I want to determine whether the spikes are caused due to some delay in this code or whether some other task started running inside the CPU because of which this operation took time. I have tried using `GetThreadTimes` API to see how much time my thread spent inside CPU but am unable to conclude based on those numbers. What is the standard way to go about troubleshooting these types of issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the standard way to go about troubleshooting these types of issues?

There are Real Time Operating Systems (RTOS) which guarantee those kind of delays. It is totally different class of operating systems than Windows or Linux.

But still, there are something you can do about your delays even on general purpose OS.

#### 1. Avoid system calls

Once you ask your OS to read or write something to a disk -- there are no guarantees whatever about delays. So, avoid any system functions on you critical path:

- even functions like gettimeofday() might cause unpredictable delays, so you should really avoid any system calls in time-critical code;
- use another thread to perform IO and pass data via a shared buffer to your critical code.

If your code base is big, tools like `strace` on Linux or `Dr Memory` on Windows to trace system calls.

#### 2. Avoid context switches

The multi threading on Windows is preemptive. It means, there is a system scheduler, which might stop your thread any time and schedule another thread on your CPU. As previously, there are RTOSes, which allow to avoid such context switches, but there is something you can do about it:

- make sure there is at least one CPU core left for system and other tasks;
- bind each of your threads to a dedicated CPU with `SetThreadAffinityMask()` (Windows) or `sched_setaffinity()` (Linux) -- this effectively hints system scheduler to avoid scheduling other threads on this CPU;
- make sure hardware interrupts go to another CPU; usually interrupts go to CPU 0, so the easiest way would be to bind your thread with CPU 1+;
- increase your thread priority, so scheduler less likely to switch your thread with another one.

There are tools like `perf` (Linux) and `Intel VTune` (Windows) to confirm there are context switches.

#### 3. Avoid other non-deterministic features

Few more sources of unexpected delays:

- disable swap, so you know for sure your thread memory will not be swapped on slow and unpredictable disk drive;
- disable CPU turbo boost -- after a high-performance CPU boosts, there is always a slow down, so the CPU stays withing its thermal power (TDP);
- disable hyper threading -- from scheduler point of view those are independent CPUs, but in fact performance of each hyper-thread CPU depend on what another thread is doing at the moment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Reason behind sudden spikes during processing could be any of IO, interrupt, scheduled processes etc.

It is very common to see such spikes considering such low latency/processing time operations. IMO you can consider them because of any of the above mentioned reasons (There could be more). Simplest solution is run same experiment with more inputs multiple times and take the average for final consideration.

To answer your question about checking/confirming source of the spike you can try following,

1. Check variation in images - already ruled out as per your comment
2. Monitor resource utilization during processing. Check if any resource is choking (% util is simplest way to check and SAR/NMON utility on linux is best with minimal overhead)
3. Reserve few CPU's on system (CPU Affinity) for your experiment which are dedicated only for your program and no OS task will run on them. Taskset is simplest utility to try out. More details are [here](http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html).

Run the experiment with this setting and check behavior.

Comment: Disabling hyperthreading could be useful too; another process competing with yours for cache and other shared resources can slow you down even if your thread is never interrupted.  (Of course, if your code is sensitive to L3 cache pollution / disturbances, any other activity will hurt).

Answer (score 2):

That's a nasty thing you are trying to figure out, I wouldn'd even attempt to, since coming into concrete conlusions is hard.

In general, one should run a loop of *many* iterations (100 just seems too small I think), and then take the average time for an image to be processed.

That will rule out any unexpected exterior events that may have hurt performance of your program.

---

A typical way to check if "some other task started running inside the CPU" would be to run your program once and mark the images that produce that spike. Example, image 2, 4, 5, and 67 take too long to be processed. Run your program again some times, and mark again which images produce the spikes.

If the same images produce these spikes, then it's not something caused by another exterior task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. to rule out specific images causing issue, I ran the algorithm on the same image 100 times. Even then I see spikes.